# C# - Convert to string the significant part from a hex/ulong value

Tags: c#, string, ulong

How can I take as a string the significant part of a hex/ulong number?

For example, if I have 0x00000321321, I want to get "321321".

If I try something like:

```
ulong x = 0x0000023632763;
string s = x.toString();
```

I get `593700707`, so it is not what i want.

Is that possible ?

Thank you!

Comment: See the Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString

Comment: toString() should be ToString()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ToString(string format)` override with a [standard hexadecimal formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) `"x"` <s>, along with `TrimStart()` to get rid of leading zeros</s>:

```
string s = x.ToString("x");
```

(Thanks to Keith N. for pointing out the `Trim` is not necessary.)

Comment: I remember I already tried this. It works, but not for values like 0x003DEF. I will try again. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, i was doing something wrong. I think I tried this on a hex string, not on a hex value, that's why it was not working. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 3):

How about x.toString("x")? I don't have a C# handy to try it out but that should output the number in hex. See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

very easy...  to string has lots of options on how to create strings...

```
x.ToString("X");
```

it will only convert the significant part.   Only choice is x or X controls whether you get capital letters or not for hex digits.

Answer (score 1):

ToString suports the standard nnumeric format. Here is the e MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

```
int value; 

value = 0x2045e;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("x"));
// Displays 2045e
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("X"));
// Displays 2045E
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("X8"));
// Displays 0002045E
```